# How to edit code_editor.xml to enable dark theme?

Tags: mysql-workbench

I am trying to edit the code_editor.xml file (C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\data) to enable the dark theme (or dark colors for the fonts/ editor bg etc) in MySQL Workbench IDE.

I am getting following alert when I try to edit the file manually.

[---------------------------

### Save failed

### Please check whether if this file is opened in another program

### OK

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVos2.jpg)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVos2.jpg):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/csfre.png

[screenshot=> File Edit Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVos2.jpg)

Please help me to edit the file.

[Status of mysql Services](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0ixr.png)

Answer (score 0):

Just close all the services that are related to mysql and re-open de file as administrator.

Comment: I tried that, closed 2 services (workbench exe & mysql exe from task manager Plus the eclipse IDE), but still got the same error.
I am already logged in as admin.

Comment: I think that you are closing the processes, not the services.

Comment: do you mean the above service ? (attached the pic in the Question section).
It seems to be in stopped status.